# Why does Sybase ASE throw a truncation error in a division followed by a subtraction?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am using Sybase ASE 15.  In the following SQL, there is a truncation error, but only if the division of two numbers is followed by a subtraction.

```
    declare @P1  decimal (30,16)
    declare @P2  decimal (30,16)
    select @P1 = 0.0000504412630951  --sixteen decimal places
    select @P2 = 0.0000512178647912
    select 'This succeeds:'
    select @P1, @P2, (@P1 / @P2)          --this succeeds: displays the values
    select 'This fails:'
    select @P1, @P2, (@P1 / @P2)  - 1.0  --this fails with a truncation error.  Why?
    select 'Why does this succeed?'
    select @P1, @P2, round( (@P1 / @P2), 46 )  - 1.0  --this succeeds with 46 or less, fails with 47 or greater - but why?
```

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

The 1.0 is not a decimal datatype like `@P1` and `@P2` , it's created as a float since you do not specify the precision and scale (or cast it as a numeric/decimal data type).  The first attempt succeeds because there is no implicit conversion, you're dividing two decimals with the same precision/scale.  The 2nd attempt fails because subtracting 1.0 is subtracting a float value of 1.0 against a decimal which forces an implicit conversion back to decimal. Since it is implied and not explicit, you get the truncation error because the system wants you to know that you are losing scale by doing the given operation. The Round function in the 3rd attempt is doing an explicit conversion, so any truncation is ignored because you are telling the system what you want out of the operation.

You can find some more information on the scale error at the link below, even how to turn it off if you don't care about it (look towards the bottom of the page).

[SyBooks Online - Conversion Error Handling](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug647.htm)